# Solve $x^4-12x^2+36 \le 0$

Tags: inequality

> Solve: $$x^4-12x^2+36 \le 0.$$

Let us try to solve $x^4-12x^2+36=0 \iff (x^2-6)^2=0 \iff x^2-6=0 \iff x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{6}.$ Now we should plot the roots on the number line.
[image]

Are there any practical rules that I can use to determine the sign of the polynomial in each of the intervals faster?

Comment: Sign in each interval is positive. It alternates with every root, but since points here are double roots, the polynomial will always remain positive.

Comment: Well, you can always check the derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to solve $x^4 - 12x^2 + 36 \leq 0.$ This can be written as $(x^2 - 6)^2 \leq 0.$

Can a square be negative? Can it be zero?